# Order of Elements in Quotient Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let *G* be a group, and *H* a normal subgroup of *G*. Prove that, for each element *a* in *G*, the order of the element *Ha* in *G/H* is a divisor of the order of *a* in *G*.

So I have already done a lot of stuff with homomorphisms and the order of elements, and I know G/H is a homomorphic image of G. I'm just not sure how I can apply this to quotient groups.

a<sup>n</sup> = e for some n in G. Does this mean that I'm looking for some Hn = e? I guess I'm having a hard time thinking of Ha as an element.

Comment: Prove that in general, if $f$ is a group homomorphism, then the order of $f(a)$ divides the order of $a$

Comment: I've done that for a previous problem. I just don't know how to express *Ha* as *f(a)*. I know for (f(a))^n you eventually get e because homomorphisms preserve the operation. Again, I understand it conceptually for homomorphisms, but I'm having trouble with cosets and quotient groups and notation.

Comment: Simply let $f(a) := Ha$ :) (This is usually called the canonical homomorphism and is denoted as $\pi(a)$)

Answer (score 6):

For quotient group $G/H$, you need to remember that its element is $Hg$, where $g\in G$, and $He=H$ is the identity of $G/H$. The multiplication is $(Hg)(Hg_1)=Hgg_1$. Now let $m$ be the order of $a$, then $(Ha)^m=Ha^m=H$, this means the order of $Ha$ is a divisor of $m$.

Answer (score 3):

Prove by induction that $f(a^n)=f(a)^n$ for any homomorphism $f$. Then if $a$ has order $n$, $f(a^n)=f(a)^n=e$.
Suppose $|f(a)|=k$. Then there are natural numbers $q,r$ such that $n=qk+r$, where $r<k$. If $r \not= 0$, then $f(a)^r=f(a)^{n-qk}=e$. This is a contradiction since $k$ is the smallest number such that $f(a)^k=e$.